# Zclip on multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, zclip

I'm trying to implement zclip to copy input's content into clipboard.
There is 20 text inputs on the page like this:

```
<input type="text" value="content to copy..." />
<input type="text" value="another content to copy..." />
```

And I came up with this jQuery code:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("input[type=text]").click(function() {
    var link = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery(this).zclip({
        path: '/img/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: link
    });
  });
});
```

In the Javascript console I get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function.

How can I get this working?
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems as if you use jQuery in noConflict mode. ZClip assumes that this is not the case and tries to extend the '$'. I just replaced every '$' in the jquery.zclip.js with 'jQuery' and the error message disappeared.
If there is another way to run zClip in noConflict mode let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Use `each` instead of click and use a function to return the link value

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("input[type=text]").each(function() {
    var link = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery(this).zclip({
        path: '/img/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: function(){return link;}
    });
  });
});
```